# Obtaining the object id of a newly created object via AJAX Post

Tags: javascript, ajax, django-views, http-post

I have this AJAX post function that is working as expected but the problem is with the remove button. I need to add the id of the object to the value of the remove button because I have another removeFriend function that relies on the value of the remove button to delete the correct row.

```
function addNewFriend(formData){

    const friendForm = document.querySelector('#friend-form');
    const nicknameInput = document.querySelector('#id_nick_name');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/friend",
        data: formData,
        success: function (response) {
            // on successfull creating object
            // 1. clear the form.
            friendForm.reset();
            // 2. focus to nickname input 
            nicknameInput.focus();

            // display the new friend to table.
            var instance = JSON.parse(response["instance"]);
            var fields = instance[0]["fields"];
            const row = document.createElement('tr');
            row.innerHTML = `
            <td>${fields["nick_name"]}</td>
            <td>${fields["first_name"]}</td>
            <td>${fields["last_name"]}</td>
            <td>${fields["likes"]}</td>
            <td>${fields["dob"]}</td>
            <td>${fields["lives_in"]}</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="remove-friend" name="remove-friend" value="${fields["id"]}">Remove</button></td>
            `;
            const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
            tbody.appendChild(row);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            // alert the error if any error occured
            alert(response["responseJSON"]["error"]);
        }
    })
}
```

When I create a new friend and it is appended to the table at the bottom of the webpage, if I immediately go to try and remove that friend it throws an error. Once I refresh the page, I am able to remove that friend just fine. Immediately after adding a new friend I go to the Chrome browser Elements bar and I can see that the remove button value for that newly added friend is "undefined" so I know that the error lies in how I am dynamically creating the button and assigning the value.

I tried setting the value of remove button to:
`value=${instance["id"]}` and had the same outcome.

This is my **views.py**

```
def postFriend(request):
    
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        
        form = FriendForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            
            ser_instance = serializers.serialize('json', [ instance, ])
           
            return JsonResponse({"instance": ser_instance}, status=200)
        else:
           
            return JsonResponse({"error": form.errors}, status=400)

 
    return JsonResponse({"error": ""}, status=400)
```

Can anyone see how I can obtain the object Id of the newly created friend so that I can correctly set the value of the remove button?

**Addition as requested: removeFriend function**

```
     document.querySelector('tbody').addEventListener('click', function(e){
         if(e.target.innerHTML == 'Remove'){
             e.preventDefault();
             console.log("Remove friend btn clicked?");
             console.log(e.target.value);
             removeFriend(e.target.value)
         }
     })

function removeFriend(id){

    let dataId = `${id}`

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: `/delete/friend`,
        data: {
            friend_id: `${id}`,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            action: 'post'
        },
        success: function(json){
            let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
            let row = tbody.querySelector(`tr[data-id="${id}"]`);
            console.log(row);
            row.remove();
            alert('friend has been deleted')
        },
        error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: can you also add the remove friend function?

Comment: @HymnZzy I have edited my post accordingly

Comment: Yea. The problem is that `addEventListener` applies only to items that are present when the page first loaded.

Comment: Do the other fields in the row populate, what do you get if you conaole.log(response)??

Comment: Thank you @Musa. `console.log(response)` helped me see the new object that was created and from there I was able to figure out how to access the "pk" property and all is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Tweak your functions a little bit:

```
function addNewFriend(formData){
    ...
    <td><button type="button" class="remove-friend" name="remove-friend" onclick="removeFriend(event,'${fields["id"]}')">Remove</button></td>
    ...
}

function removeFriend(e,id){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

You can get rid of this `document.querySelector('tbody')` entire part.

What we are doing here is defining an `onclick` attribute to the button which will trigger the `removeFriend` function directly.

Edit: Added `preventDefault` directly in `removeFriend` function to disable form submit.